# Element not being rendered in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-boot

I've just started my adventure with angular. I have very simple application which is supposed to present the content of json fetched from controller (Spring Boot asap created app). View is supposed to show the list of people, which works as it should with the json provided within the controller, however when I'm switching to $http.get, the list is not being rendered.

I know that controller is being asked for a data (I have logs, and did the debugging on front end side) it is just an empty view, which is a bit problematic. I somehow have the feeling that it is connected with `$scope`, but I'm too fresh to understand what's wrong.

Here is my code:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="peoplePopulator">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="app/peoplePopulator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<people-consumer></people-consumer>
</body>
</html>
```

**myApp.js:**

```
var peoplePopulator = angular.module('peoplePopulator', []);
```

**peoplePopulator.js:**

```
angular.module('peoplePopulator').component('peopleConsumer', {
    template:
    '<ul>' +
    '<li ng-repeat="man in $ctrl.people">' +
    '<p>This is the value for id: {{man.id}}</p>' +
    '<p>This is the value for name: {{man.name}}</p>' +
    '<p>This is the value for surname: {{man.surname}}</p>' +
    '<p>This is the value for age: {{man.age}}</p>' +
    '<p>This is the value for sex: {{man.sex}}</p>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</ul>',
    controller: function PeopleController($scope, $http) {
       $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getAllPeople').
                then(function(response) {
                    $scope.people = response.data;
                });
    }
});
```

**Log:**

```
Added: PersonDto{id=null, name='ran1.6077897002879162E308', surname='dom389401569', age=423647022, sex='F'}
Added: PersonDto{id=null, name='ran1.7927508063734304E308', surname='dom139179403', age=135916746, sex='F'}
Added: PersonDto{id=null, name='ran5.491516947272879E307', surname='dom601187307', age=1882764612, sex='F'}
Fetching records from all over the world
HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Fetching records from all over the world <- logger in the getAllPeople controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threre're two alternative ways to create angularjs components: directive (older and has more features https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and component (newer, a subset of directive, it helps to define sane defaults and migrate to Angular 2+ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). You used component in the code. This means you're operating with $ctrl in the view by default. Your code should therefore look like this:

```
 controller: function PeopleController($scope, $http) {
   var $ctrl = this;
   $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getAllPeople').
            then(function(response) {
                $ctrl.people = response.data;
            });
}
```